# Is the vendor directory generated from composer (php's library manager) the same in linux and windows?

Tags: php, linux, windows, composer-php

I need this because I'm learning docker and am deciding whether I can just auto copy it on deploy.

Comment: You should run composer into Linux. While running composer it will update folder path or adding extension into auto loader file. Windows and linux have different path. Thank you

Comment: Are you saying they are different? Say a composer package has a symlink, windows and linux will have their own way of handling the symlink, am I correct?

Answer (score -1):

They are the same, check the code below:

`autoload.php` in Windows:

```
<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit544b12ff5592aafaae7e8d3f3b9e665e::getLoader();
```

`autoload.php` in Linux:

```
<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit544b12ff5592aafaae7e8d3f3b9e665e::getLoader();
```

Also keep in mind they have to be the same, we are using github to keep project files organized, sometimes I do developement in Linux and sometimes in windows, and of course we are using composer, so rest assured, they are the same.